# Formatting a given currency for various locales in java? (Rounding issue)

Tags: java, format, locale, currency

I am trying to format a currency based on the accept-language header, but I'm having a little trouble.

1. An English-US user will understand € 10,000,000.15 but not the suitable-for-Germany equivalent, € 10.000.000,15
2. On the other hand, "$23,123 looks" fine to an English-US user, but "$23,123.00" looks very strange. So does "JPY23,123.00". The latter is what I get using the following code:

   ```
    java.text.NumberFormat format = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale.US);
    format.setCurrency(java.util.Currency.getInstance("JPY"));
   ```
3. Even more disturbing is the rounding that happens when I display USD in ja_JP.
   if I format 7.95, it just shows as "USD8" instead of "USD7.95"

Is there any simple way to avoid this? Is there a better library for formatting currencies? Should I just format it as a number for the locale (if the currency isn't the locale's default), and then prepend the currency code or symbol?

Comment: You'd better translate your example into real code. For example, how do you get "$23,123", what you expect the output is. That will make the question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default 10000000.15 euro is printed as `EUR10,000,000.15` for Locale.US and `10.000.000,15 €` for Locale.GERMANY and it seems correct.

But `USD8` for $7.75 looks really weird even for Japan. But this can be fixed:

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    format.setCurrency(currency);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(currency.getDefaultFractionDigits());
    System.out.println(format.format(7.95));
```

it prints `USD7.95` for JAPAN/USD and `JPY8` for US/JPY

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for. I also ended up doing format.setMinimumFractionDigits(currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()) so that it *always* displays the default number of digits. (so $7.50 will display as USD7.50 not USD7.5)